# Intuition behind Martingale convergence theorem

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, martingales

I just learned martingale convergence theorem today which is the following:

> If $X_n$ is a submartingale with $\sup EX_n^+<\infty$ then as $n\to\infty$, $X_n$ converges almost surely to a limit $X$ with $E|X|<\infty$.

I want to ask two questions and think of them intuitively (not technically):

(1) What does martingale convergence theorem tell us?

(2) Why martingale convergence should be true?

My thoughts are looking for simple and instructive examples. I loved the example where the terminology "martingale" comes from. We bet \$1 on fair coin flippings. Let $S_n$ be a symmetric simple random walk representing the money up to time $n$ with $S_0=1$ where $S_n=S_{n-1}+\xi_n$ and $P(\xi_i=1)=1/2=P(\xi_i=-1)$. Let $N=\inf\{n:S_n=0\}$ be the stopping time. Let $X_n=S_{N\land n}$ be the martingale representing that we will stop when we lose all money. Let $$H_m=\begin{cases}2H_{m-1}, & \xi_{m-1}=-1\\ 1, & \xi_{m-1}=1 \end{cases}$$ be the martingale gambling system.

Now, consider the martingale $Y_n:=(H\cdot X)_n$ which characterizes the amount of money up to time $n$ in the martingale gambling game. Assume that on average we will only have finite amount of money at any time $n$, then $Y_n$ converges to $0$ almost surely which tells us that we will lose all the money finally : ( As for question (2), the essential reason is that the condition of finite amount of money implies finiteness of upcrossings for any rational intervals $[a,b]$ which implies a convergence.

Please let me know if you have any ideas or comments. Thanks!

Comment: As a first intuition you can think about it as a gambling process as well. In this context, assuming that $X_n$ is a submartingale means that your expected profit between two consecutive gambling rounds is positive. In other words, your wealth should increase on average. That said, the supremum condition prevents your wealth from increasing too fast. In fact, your expected wealth is bounded from above. And like most monotone, bounded things in Mathematics, if your wealth is bounded but expected to increase, then it will converge.